# How to add an image subview to a tableview programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to programming, and I know how to add a static image behind a tableView in a `.xib` file, but not in code. I have tried the following code:

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
[self.view addSubView: image];
```

but nothing happens when I write this!

Comment: Here's a tip dude. You need to accept answers for all your questions, if it had helped you. Otherwise people wont spend time on your questions.

Answer (score 3):

To display an UIImage you have to use an UIImageView and put it under the UITableView using the same frame. Don't forget to set the table view's background to transparent.

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]];
iv.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 600.0);
UITableView *tv = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:iv.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
tv.opaque = NO;
tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubView: iv];
[self.view addSubView: tv];
[iv release];
[tv release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a UIImageView, not a UIImage.  Also, when adding a view programmatically, don't forget to set the frame.

Comment: ok thank you very much! and why and how do i need to set the frame? Thanks man :D

Comment: The frame tells the view where to layout with respect to its parent.  You set through the property "view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200);" or something like that.  This is pretty intro stuff, so probably a good idea to read through some tutorials to get you started.  http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-creating-basic-buttons